# HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed with paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, lamp, http-status-code-405

I receive this error message `HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed` when I try the paypal ipm simulator. I found this link `http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html` it sounds like since its coming from another domain it gets blocked. Because POST and GET work fine. So I know the issue but I have no clue what to change on the server, I am familiar with putty and apache/php config any ideas or suggestions for me to fix it would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?